# PostgreSQL GIN index on array of uuid

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing, uuid

I would like to use a GIN index on `uuid[]` (to have efficient membership tests for arrays of uuids). However when I try it PostgreSQL gives me an error:

```
mydb=> CREATE TABLE foo (val uuid[]);
CREATE TABLE
mydb=> CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON foo USING GIN(val);
ERROR:  data type uuid[] has no default operator class for access method "gin"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

How can I add the necessary operator class so that it works?

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082625/postgresql-9-2-gin-index-on-citext) is a similar question for the type `citext` but the provided answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of PostgreSQL 10 the custom operator class `_uuid_ops` is no longer necessary as there is now a general built-in opclass `array_ops` on `anyarry` (see:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html)

Comment: Thanks @tbussmann, I referenced your answer in my original one.

Answer (score 30):

**Note:** this answer is obsolete as this is now part of a standard PostgreSQL, see tbussmann's other answer (which you should upvote).

**Original answer:**

This can be done using the following operator class:

```
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS _uuid_ops DEFAULT 
  FOR TYPE _uuid USING gin AS 
  OPERATOR 1 &&(anyarray, anyarray), 
  OPERATOR 2 @>(anyarray, anyarray), 
  OPERATOR 3 <@(anyarray, anyarray), 
  OPERATOR 4 =(anyarray, anyarray), 
  FUNCTION 1 uuid_cmp(uuid, uuid), 
  FUNCTION 2 ginarrayextract(anyarray, internal, internal), 
  FUNCTION 3 ginqueryarrayextract(anyarray, internal, smallint, internal, internal, internal, internal), 
  FUNCTION 4 ginarrayconsistent(internal, smallint, anyarray, integer, internal, internal, internal, internal), 
  STORAGE uuid;
```

Credits to [this](http://www.sql.ru/forum/798928/uuid-nepolnaya-podderzhka-tipa-kto-kak-vykruchivaetsya) for pointing me in the right direction.

The relevant documentation is in [Interfacing extensions to indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xindex.html), in particular the operator strategy and function numbers for GIN are described there.

Comment: Curious to know: might adding btree_gin have been enough, or was the above required?

Comment: No, [btree_gin](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/btree-gin.html) does not include array types.

Comment: Just a note, you can't use this on Heroku or any other postgres host, as it requires superuser privs to create an operator class!

Comment: I tried using this on PostGres 9.6 but after running it I receive the same error as the OP.  I thought maybe the underscore in `FOR TYPE _uuid` was a typo, but when I create `FOR TYPE uuid` I get another error when creating the index `cache lookup failed for type 3177436692` . Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What about upgrades? Should we drop this operator class definition if, say, we go from 9.6 to version 10?